# TestNG: Test Method In Second Class of Test Suite Being Called Only Once

Tags: java, testng, rest-assured

I have two test methods in different classes. The first method, let's say "createCustomer" is using dataProvider to get the inputs from an excel file and creates three customers.

```
 @Test(dataProvider = "createCustomerTestData", dataProviderClass = createCustomerDataProvider.class)
    public void addStockAccountWithAllInput(ITestContext context) throws JsonProcessingException {

    //Rest-Assured code goes here

        ISuite suite = context.getSuite();
        suite.setAttribute("customerID", js.get("customerID"));

}
```

The second method, let's say "getCustomer" is supposed to get the id of the customers from output of "createCustomer" method and use them as input, using ITestContext and ISuite.

```
@Test
public void testGetCustomer(ITestContext context) {

    ISuite suite = context.getSuite();

//Rest-Assured code goes here

    Assert.assertEquals(js.getString("customerID"), suite.getAttribute("customerID"));
}
```

When I run the test suite from the testng xml file, only the id of the third created customer will be passed to "getCustomer" method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All Test Suite">
    <test verbose="2" preserve-order="true"         
        <classes>
            <class name="addCustomer">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testAddCustomer"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test verbose="2" preserve-order="true"
                  <classes>
            <class name="getCustomer">
                <methods>
                     <include name="testGetCustomer"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

How can I change the settings or the code so that the "getCustomer" method gets called every time createCustomer is called and a customer created?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1. testAddCustomer --> Save `id` to a List 2. testGetCustomer  --> for each id in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you.

```
//Create a temp list of String to save ID
static List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();

@Test(dataProvider = "createCustomerTestData", dataProviderClass = createCustomerDataProvider.class)
public void addStockAccountWithAllInput(ITestContext context) throws JsonProcessingException {

    //Rest-Assured code goes here

    ISuite suite = context.getSuite();
    String id = js.get("customerID");
    ids.add(id);
    suite.setAttribute("customerIDs", ids);
}

@Test
public void testGetCustomer(ITestContext context) {

    ISuite suite = context.getSuite();

    //Make api call based on the list IDs from above test 
    for (int i = 0; i < suite.getAttribute("customerIDs").size(); i++){
        //Rest-Assured code goes here
        Assert.assertEquals(js.getString("customerID"), suite.getAttribute("customerIDs").get(i));
    }
}
```